# How to change the colors to a triangular graph using ggplot?

Tags: r

This is my script. I want to personalize the colors to the triangle that is drawn by hand, so that the inner points are of one color and the lines of another. Is this possible? The result is a triangular graph with scattered points in the interior and three interior lines that mark the average, this is what you want to change so that it changes color and the background comes out transparent, using ggplot

```
library (adespatial) 

library (adespatial)

library (ade4)
library (betapart)
if (require(ade4, quietly = TRUE))
data(habitat)
habitat.pod.J <- beta.div.comp(habitat, coef = "J", quant = FALSE)
# Sorensen
habitat.pod.S <- beta.div.comp(habitat, coef = "S", quant = FALSE)
# Ruzicka
habitat.pod.qJ <- beta.div.comp(habitat, coef = "J", quant = TRUE)
# Percentage difference
habitat.pod.qS <- beta.div.comp(habitat, coef = "S", quant = TRUE)
# Data frames for the triangular plots
# Data frames for the triangular plots
habitat.pod.J.3 <- cbind((1-habitat.pod.J$D),
habitat.pod.J$repl,
habitat.pod.J$rich)
colnames(habitat.pod.J.3) <- c("Similarity", "Repl", "RichDiff")
habitat.pod.S.3 <- cbind((1-habitat.pod.S$D),
habitat.pod.S$repl,
habitat.pod.S$rich)
colnames(habitat.pod.S.3) <- c("Similarity", "Repl", "RichDiff")
habitat.pod.qJ.3 <- cbind((1-habitat.pod.qJ$D),
habitat.pod.qJ$repl,
habitat.pod.qJ$rich)
colnames(habitat.pod.qJ.3) <- c("Similarity", "Repl", "AbDiff")
habitat.pod.qS.3 <- cbind((1-habitat.pod.qS$D),
habitat.pod.qS$repl,
habitat.pod.qS$rich)
colnames(habitat.pod.qS.3) <- c("Similarity", "Repl", "AbDiff")
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
triangle.plot(as.data.frame(habitat.pod.J.3[, c(3, 1, 2)]),
show = FALSE,
labeltriangle = FALSE,
addmean = TRUE
)
text(-0.45, 0.5, "RichDiff", cex = 1.5)
text(0.4, 0.5, "Repl", cex = 1.5)
text(0, -0.6, "Jaccard similarity", cex = 1.5)
triangle.plot(as.data.frame(habitat.pod.S.3[, c(3 ,1 ,2)]),
show = FALSE,
labeltriangle = FALSE,
addmean = TRUE
)
text(-0.45, 0.5, "RichDiff", cex = 1.5)
text(0.4, 0.5, "Repl", cex = 1.5)
text(0, -0.6, "Sorensen similarity", cex = 1.5)
triangle.plot(as.data.frame(habitat.pod.qJ.3[, c(3, 1, 2)]),
show = FALSE,
labeltriangle = FALSE,
addmean = TRUE
)
text(-0.45, 0.5, "AbDiff", cex = 1.5)
text(0.4, 0.5, "Repl", cex = 1.5)
text(0, -0.6, "S = 1 – Ružička D", cex = 1.5)
triangle.plot(as.data.frame(habitat.pod.qS.3[, c(3, 1, 2)]),
show = FALSE,
labeltriangle = FALSE,
addmean = TRUE
)
text(-0.45, 0.5, "AbDiff", cex = 1.5)
text(0.4, 0.5, "Repl", cex = 1.5)
text(0, -0.6, "S = 1 – Percentage difference", cex = 1.5)
# Display values of the mean points in the triangular plots
colMeans(habitat.pod.J.3[, c(3, 1, 2)])
colMeans(habitat.pod.S.3[, c(3, 1, 2)])
colMeans(habitat.pod.qJ.3[, c(3, 1, 2)])
```

the inner points of a color and the inner lines of a different color. Is this possible?

Comment: Instead of giving is your entire script (most of which is not relevant to drawing triangles), could you just concoct a simple dataset and a simple few lines of code to draw the triangles? The amount of code is daunting and likely a turn-off for some potential answerers. (BTW: your use if `require` is broken: sure, you don't try to load the data if the package is not found, but ... then you use that data on the next line of code. So the script will still fail badly if the package is not available.)

Comment: All is OK II cant disminuye the code, i don't know how change the code for the colors, try in https://rstudio.cloud